# Jquery Mobile taphold event is not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and having an issue. Click works,

```
$(document).delegate('#id', 'click', function () {
        alert('Tapped');
});
```

But taphold does not,

```
$(document).delegate('#id', 'taphold', function () {
        alert('Tapped');
});
```

Comment: mobile phones or desktop browsers?

Comment: It now works? What did you do to fix it? Considering answering the question for future visitors

Comment: @TomWalters, I have updated the question which include the answer

Comment: It makes more sense to actually answer your own question then accept that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works. I just needed to place this event inside pageshow like,

```
    $(document).delegate('div[data-role*="page"]', 'pageshow', function () {
        $(document).delegate('#id', 'taphold', function (evt) {
        });
    });
```